# Convert command doesn't work (liblzma.so.0)

Tags: imagemagick

My convert command doesn't work. If I run the command:

```
convert -resize 448x448^ srcimg.png dstimg.png
```

I get the following error:

```
convert: error while loading shared libraries: liblzma.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I try to locate the file `liblzma.so.0` I don't get any result. Instead this is the output of `locate liblzma.so`:

```
/home/ep15/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/liblzma.so
/home/ep15/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/liblzma.so.5
/home/ep15/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/liblzma.so.5.2.2
/home/ep15/anaconda2/lib/liblzma.so
/home/ep15/anaconda2/lib/liblzma.so.5
/home/ep15/anaconda2/lib/liblzma.so.5.0.5
/home/ep15/anaconda2/pkgs/xz-5.0.5-1/lib/liblzma.so
/home/ep15/anaconda2/pkgs/xz-5.0.5-1/lib/liblzma.so.5
/home/ep15/anaconda2/pkgs/xz-5.0.5-1/lib/liblzma.so.5.0.5
/home/ep15/anaconda2/pkgs/xz-5.2.2-0/lib/liblzma.so
/home/ep15/anaconda2/pkgs/xz-5.2.2-0/lib/liblzma.so.5
/home/ep15/anaconda2/pkgs/xz-5.2.2-0/lib/liblzma.so.5.2.2
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so
/usr/local/anaconda2/lib/liblzma.so
/usr/local/anaconda2/lib/liblzma.so.5
/usr/local/anaconda2/lib/liblzma.so.5.0.5
/usr/local/anaconda2/pkgs/xz-5.0.5-1/lib/liblzma.so
/usr/local/anaconda2/pkgs/xz-5.0.5-1/lib/liblzma.so.5
/usr/local/anaconda2/pkgs/xz-5.0.5-1/lib/liblzma.so.5.0.5
```

I tried to solve with a symbolic link but then another error comes out. What could be the problem?

edit:
the output after I made the symbolic link 'sudo ln -svf /usr/local/anaconda2/lib/liblzma.so liblzma.so.0':

```
convert: error while loading shared libraries: libgvc.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Perhaps try `$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall imagemagick` ?

Comment: What exactly is this "another error"? I would try the symbolic link solution as well.

Comment: Imagemagick in the Ubuntu repositories (12.04 and newer) uses liblzma5, not liblzma(0). You seem to be using an ancient or non-Ubuntu version of imagemagick. We can't help you with those beyond suggesting that you migrate to a supported version.

Comment: I tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall imagemagick` , but didn't solve the problem

Comment: Do you have a different (older) version of `convert` installed manually? Try `whereis convert` or `which convert`

Comment: `which convert` output:  `/home/myname/anaconda2/bin/convert`

`whereis convert` output: `/usr/bin/convert /usr/bin/convert.im6 /usr/bin/X11/convert /usr/bin/X11/convert.im6 /usr/share/man/man1/convert.1.gz`